# By the eyes of a child

Tags: prepositions, translation

I'm translating a song from my Portuguese to English. Its title (*Aos Olhos de uma Criança*) literally means "At/on the eyes of a child". It means that the things said in this song are being witnessed by a child. Does it sound natural to translate it to "By the eyes of a child" with no verbs?

Comment: What does "aos" mean? Is there a direct translation?

Comment: It's the contraction of **a** (a preposition) + **os** (the masculine plural definite article). The translation of the preposition depends on the context. "_Epístola **aos** Romanos_": _Epistle **to the** Romans_. "_Estou **a** sua disposição_": _I'm **at** your disposal_.

Comment: Oh I see, it is like in French "de" + "le" = "du" if I remember correctly. Portuguese is giving me a hard time :D Estar vs Ser......:'(

Comment: I just committed to the new SE site :) What I don't understand is that older addresses still include "google" instead of only "g".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Titles are able to be fragments of sentences, so yes, that title would be fine. (Another translation might be "In the eyes of a child," or "Through the eyes of a child." But *because* those are both common sayings in English, "By the eyes of a child" would be more unique.)

Comment: Thank you! By the way, if you're comfortable with it, you should add your location to your profile. It may be useful for us when you answer questions about things that are said differently in other countries.

Comment: Tweaked, for the US. (I usually leave that blank for privacy concerns.)